# Using external data source (like JTA) in Java SE

Tags: java, datasource, jta

> Is it possible to use an external data source (such as jta) in java standard environment?

I think that the answer is no. But I'd like a confirm.

I think it is not possible to use a jta-data-source because it is usually deployed by an application server. Since a java SE application can't use an application server (unlike a JAVA EE application), it won't be able to use an external data source.

But maybe there are other kind of external data source?

Comment: JTA is for managing distributed transactions.  You cannot use it in simple SE application.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'd like to set an external data source. I'd rather not write informations concerning my db connection (such as host, username, password etc...) in my java code. My code just reads three table from DB and writes one table. I'd like a portable code trough different environments without binding java code to db infos.

Comment: So just use plain old JDBC

Comment: how not to write in the code username, password etc..?

Comment: @OldProgrammer, do you mean I should save these information in a file? Would it be safe?